# Reading gdb values correctly after mov

Tags: c, linux, assembly, gdb, x86

Here are two lines of a binary I am debugging in gdb. This was C code compiled by gcc for an IA32:

```
8049345:    8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
8049348:    89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
```

I have a `display $eax` set up so it will show the value after each step. After the first line, the `display` says: `6: $eax = 134527652`.

I can `x 134527652` or `x $eax` and I see `0x804baa4 <input_strings+100>:    "1 1 1 1 1 1"` Why do display and x give me different results?

The next line I believe says to move eax into the address stored by esp? I had a `display $esp` setup and it says: `2: $esp = (void *) 0xffffd540`.

Before the second mov, I `x 0xffffd540` and see: `0xffffd540:    ""` after the mov I repeat and see:

```
0xffffd540:  "\244\272\004\bY\233\004\b\210\325\377\377\214\325\377\377\220\325\377\377\224\325\377\377\230\325\377\377\234\325\377\377\001"
```

I thought this line was going to mov eax into this address, but I am obviously not understanding something here? Let me know if you would like to see any other lines from the binary.

Comment: I think you're confused about the value of eax versus the data at the address it points to. 134527652 is 0x804baa4. "1 1 1 1 1 1" is the data (interpreted as characters) at that address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your confusion may be caused by the fact that the `x` command is printing the data at address 0xffffd540 as a string. Presumably before the store to that address, the first byte at 0xffffd540 is a 0 byte, treated as terminating a string, and thus you're seeing `""`, the empty string. After writing the value 0x804baa4 to this address, you're seeing its representation in bytes:

```
\244\272\004\b
```

where `\244` (octal escape) is 0xa4, `\272` is 0xba, `\004` is 0x04, and `\b` (the escape for backspace character, U+0008) is 0x08.

You see more junk after it in the string printed because there doesn't happen to be a null terminator anymore.

Comment: Thanks @R.., I understand the first part of the answer for sure. But after the second mov why does it display that weird representation in bytes? Is there a way for me to print it out in a helpful way in gdb? Seeing `\244\272\004\b` is not as helpful to me as seeing `0x804baa4`